# Posting data to controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

first of all as a win forms developer I'm don't have much experience in web development. I'm trying my best to get the hang of it

I have two tables TOURNAMENTS_M (Master) and TOURNAMENTS_D(detail) with scaffold controllers and view.

I have edited Master tables Create/and Edit views so that I'm able to display child records as well

[image]

When I press the remove button, I call the following function

```
function DeleteDetail(pId) {
    const con = confirm("are you sure ?");


    if (con === true) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/TOURNAMENTS_M/Delete",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:
                { id: pId }
            })
            .done(function (result) {
                alert("Succeed");
            })
            .fail(function (result) {
                alert("I failed :'( ");
            });

    }
}
```

but all I get is the fail message :( what am I missing here? I really appreciate any help, been trying to make this work for hours

PS I'm using mvc core

UPDATE:

[image]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var tOURNAMENTS_M = await _context.TOURNAMENTS_M
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TM_ROWID == id);
        if (tOURNAMENTS_M == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(tOURNAMENTS_M);
    }
```

this is how I call the function

```
@if (Model != null)
{

    var i = 0;
    foreach (var detail in Model.TOURNAMENTS_D)
    {

    <tr>

        <td> <input type='hidden' name="TD_LEVEL" id='@("TD_LEVEL")@i' value="@detail.TD_LEVEL" />@detail.TD_LEVEL </td>

        <td> <input type='hidden' name="TD_SB" id='@("TD_SB")@i' value="@detail.TD_SB" />@detail.TD_SB </td>

        <td> <input type='hidden' name="TD_BB" id='@("TD_BB")@i' value="@detail.TD_BB" />@detail.TD_BB </td>


        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@detail.TD_ROWID">Edit</a> |

            <button onclick="DeleteDetail(@detail.TD_ROWID) "  class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
        i++;
    }

    //"<td><a id ='myRemove' data-itemId='0'  class='btn btn-primary'>Remove</a ></td> ";
}
```

Comment: For a start, remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (or use `data: JSON.stringify({ id: pId })`). If that does not fix the error, you need to show you controller code an indicate what the actual error is (use you browser tools - the Network tab - to inspect the response

Comment: Would be helpful to see your MVC controller action too. And is it actually being hit?

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly, the delete action is not hit, after having the fail message it hits the edit action in my controller

Comment: any errors in your browser console? And how is it hitting the Edit controller?? Perhaps we need to see how DeleteDetail() is called in the first place. Is it called from an element which is part of a form?

Comment: Just updated everything

Comment: What happens when you change the type of the request to "DELETE" instead of 'POST'?

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` element (by default its a submit button).Alternatively you can add `return false;` as the last line in your script.

Comment: changing to Delete Worked! Thanks a million times!

Comment: It would be nice to accept the answer below... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my suggestion in the comments worked, I will provide a bit more information:

Since you are using MVC Web Api out of the box, it is [a RESTful API](https://restfulapi.net/) and therefore [the method types](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) are very important.

You are trying to perform a delete action which requires a 'DELETE' type of request according the RESTful API guidelines. MVC Web Api maps this method to the `Delete` method out of the box without making use of the `[HttpDelete]` attribute.

Overall, simply change the method type of your ajax call to 'DELETE':

```
function DeleteDetail(pId) {
  const con = confirm("are you sure ?");

  if (con === true) {
     $.ajax({
        ...
        type: "DELETE",
        ...
        });
  }
}
```